# Why does my debug software say that I need a ";" somewhere in my <input> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, input

This is my code that's throwing the error:

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="start" onclick="*javascript file location*">
```

Google says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in my html on that line... my debugger says the same and that it needs a ";", is this error actually in my HTML or is it in my JavaScript somewhere? I check my code and can't find a missing semicolon.

I also checked the Javascript and the variable used is in global scope so it should be able to access it.

Comment: `*javascript file location*` a file path wouldn't be valid there. onclick and other inline js attributes are for actual javascript code. If you have actual javascript code there then show what is actually there

Comment: `onclick` should not be a javascript file location. It should be actual Javascript.

Comment: `*javascript file location*` isn't valid JavaScript, so I imagine any IDE would complain about that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Load a script from a file location on input click?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `onclick` has to be actual Javascript, and not just the file location.

Comment: This managed to fix the problem it seems, I put a function into my JavaScript that begins my listeners